# Many-to-Many, Doctrine's Entity Generator and Pluralization

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

Doctrine's many-to-many logic is confusing me a bit.  I have a pretty simple many-to-many relationship of recipes to categories.  My base entity classes are equally simple.

The Recipe entity class...

```php
class Recipe
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="categories")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="recipe_category")
     **/
    private $categories;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;


    public function __construct() {
        $this->categories = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

And the Category entity class...

```php
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Recipe")
     **/
    private $recipes;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;


    public function __construct() {
        $this->recipes = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

Seems pretty strait forward and matches Doctrine (and Symfony2's) documentation examples.  The strange behavior comes when I try and generate the getters and setters for these classes via the Symfony console app.

The relationship setters/getters are incorrect.  Take, for instance, the Category setter in the Recipe class that's generated...

```php
/**
 * Add categories
 *
 * @param \Namespace\CookbookBundle\Entity\Category $categories
 * @return Recipe
 */
public function addCategorie(\Namespace\CookbookBundle\Entity\Category $categories)
{
    $this->categories[] = $categories;

    return $this;
}
```

It looks like the auto-generation of the method name is off.  It should be "addCategory" and should be passed a "category."

While I can just correct this manually, if I re-run the entity generator, it will just add them again.

Am I doing this incorrectly or is this just a quirk of the entity generator?  Can I specify an over-ride via annotation?

Comment: Well what looks weird is that it is neither `addCategories` or `addCategory` but `addCategorie`...

Comment: Agreed.  I thought I might have screwed up some of the annotation but nothing seems to affect it which leads me to believe it's more of a core issue than an annotation/configuration problem.

Comment: I ran into the same issue myself. Just correct manually, then run doctrine:generate:entities whenever you want, it won't replace your existing methods, and the misspelled methods won't hurt anything.

Comment: On my project, i have a many to many relationship between msgCategory and superCategory entities, the generator gave me the methods: addMsgCategory and getMsgCategories

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything wrong as that's how symfony generates them. I usually don't use the app/console to generate them as currently they're not doing a good job. One example is as you've mentioned the pluralization of words as you've mentioned. Another obvious one is the fact that it's using the `[]` notation which is pretty much treating an `ArrayCollection` object as a PHP array. You **should never** treat ArrayCollections as arrays.

This is how I have implemented it myself:

```
public function addCategory(Category $category)
{
    if (!$this->categories->contains($category)
        $this->categories->add($category);

    return $this;
}
```

Which doesn't add duplicates to the Array collection if it's already added. Same thing goes with remove:

```
public function removeCategory(Category $category)
{
    if ($this->categories->contains($category)
        $this->categories->remove($category);
}
```

What I've run into many times is let's say you have 4 categories and you add and remove them

```
$r = new Recipe();
$c1 = new Category();
$c2 = new Category();


$r->addCategory($c1);
$r->addCategory($c2);
// at this point $r->getCategories()->toArray()[0] contains $c1
// and $r->getCategories()->toArray()[1] contains $c2

$r->removeCategory($c1);
// now $r->getCategories()->toArray()[0] is empty and
// $r->getCategories()->toArray()[1] contains $c2 still
// so in order to get the first category you need to:

$r->getCategories()->first();
```

Comment: I find "You should never treat ArrayCollections as arrays." false. _ArrayCollection_ implements _Collection_, which in turn implements _ArrayAccess_ precisely to be able to use ArrayCollections as arrays. Also inside _removeCategory_ method you should not use _remove_ from _ArrayCollection_ object. _remove_ method expects a key, not an element. If you want to remove an element, instead you should use _removeElement_ method. Both methods _remove_ and _removeElement_ check for the existing key/element before deleting so you also don't need to check that inside _removeCategory_.

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything wrong. It is just that Doctrine automatically tries to singularize the names of method stubs whenever there is a plural name for a collection property. This is the function that Doctrine calls when you run the command doctrine:generate:entities:

```
$methodName = Inflector::singularize($methodName);
```

In your case, Doctrine tries to 'singularize' the word *categories* but fails to recognize the singular form correctly, so it just removes an 's' from the end returning *categorie*.

Also, as you see, Doctrine does not singularize the parameter passed to the method stubs, leaving `$categories` instead of being consistent and modifying it to `$categorie`.

If you want to avoid this, either you do not use plural words for collections, or use plural words and change the methods afterwards. As @keyboardSmasher comments to your post, doctrine won't overwrite methods you already have when using the command doctrine:generate:entities, and wrong methods won't hurt much if left there alone.

---

A final note: using *ArrayCollections* as *arrays* is perfectly fine, so this code is correct:

```
$this->categories[] = $category;
```

*ArrayCollection* object implements *Collection*, which in turn implements *ArrayAccess*. It is done this way precisely to be able to use *ArrayCollections* as Arrays.